# Connecting new Pex water line to 20 yr old Pex

Tags: plumbing, pex

I'm preparing to connect new 1” Pex water line from well to 20 yr old house, that is also Pex piping. I plan to either use copper crimp rings or shark bite clamp fittings. My question is, could there be brittleness & leak issues when I compress the rings around the older Pex tubing?

Answer (score 3):

The life span of Pex can be as much as 40 years. When you make the connection to the old tubing, I would use a [**Sharkbite fitting**](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-in-Brass-Push-To-Connect-Coupling-U020LFA/202270495) at that point instead of crimping. You won't use near the pressure and they hold really well.

[image: sharkbite]

Comment: Machavity, yes using the Sharkbite ( push-on ) connection might just be the way to go. Certainly a lot less force on the tbg circumference, so thank very much for suggesting it. Still wondering though if ( you or others ) have had sealing issues using the ( clamp or crimp ) method. I imagine that the it  has been done many times during remodel jobs, and thanks big time for your help ! ! !

Comment: Went ahead & connected 1” new Pex water line to 20 yr old Pex tbg using Shark bite ( clamp method ). The old Pex didn’t seem any more harder or brittle comparing to the new Pex tbg. Been running 6 days & connection is totally dry. Mr Machavity, I did have a ( Shark Bite ) push on fitting for stand by, just in case, as you suggested above,  thanks for your suggestion, Oily Tex